# How to write the console output from powershell to a text file

Tags: powershell

I have tried many solutions to get the output of powershell to a text file so I can read it.  I can't get the console output to stop at the end so I can read it and I can't get it to write out a file. With this code a text file isn't written.  Windows 10 1903

```
:: This will Remove all Appxpackages
::
$AppsList = 'Microsoft.3DBuilder', 
'Microsoft.BingFinance', 
'Microsoft.BingNews',
'Microsoft.BingSports', 
'Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection',
'Microsoft.People', 
'Microsoft.Windows.Photos', 
'Microsoft.WindowsCamera',
'microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps', 
'Microsoft.WindowsPhone',
'Microsoft.WindowsSoundRecorder', 
'Microsoft.XboxApp', 
'Microsoft.ZuneMusic',
'Microsoft.ZuneVideo', 
'Microsoft.Getstarted', 
'Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub',
'Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider', 
'Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub',
'Fitbit.FitbitCoach',
'ThumbmunkeysLtd.PhototasticCollage'

C:\Batch\PSEXEC.EXE  -s powershell -c 
Start-Transscript -Path 'C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt'
ForEach ($App in $AppsList){
    $PackageFullName = (Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers $App).PackageFullName
    $ProPackageFullName = (Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -AllUsers | where {$_.Displayname -eq                         $App}).PackageName
write-host $PackageFullName
Write-Host $ProPackageFullName
if ($PackageFullName){
    Write-Host "Removing Package: $App"
    remove-AppxPackage -package $PackageFullName -AllUsers  > C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt
)   pause
   }

    else{
        Write-Host "Unable to find package: $App"  > C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt
   pause
    }

    if ($ProPackageFullName){
        Write-Host "Removing Provisioned Package: $ProPackageFullName"
        Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online -packagename $ProPackageFullName  >             C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt
   pause
    }

    else{
        Write-Host "Unable to find provisioned package: $App"  > C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt
   pause
    }
}
Pause
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your write-host line, you could just write the bits you need in the file (wrap in quotes) and then pipe to out-file to a txt file. eg.

```
"Unable to find package: $App" | Out-File -FilePath C:\path\to\file.txt -Append
```

Note, make sure you add -append otherwise the file will be overwritten each time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I have made the changes you suggested.  I uploaded it to this link: https://pastebin.com/CjsGJNCL  It isn't writing out the file and I'm still getting something written to the console.  Do you have any idea what is wrong? I am running this as Administrator.

Comment: The errors were from the operating system. I didn't put the errors on pastebin.  There were many changes to the script that I shared on pastebin.  Is there a different way for me to share a large change in the code?  When I find the correct answer I am happy to replace the code in my first post or post it in the answer.

Comment: Even though I followed someone elses example tried separating the bat file from the script. This is what I now have in the bat file: "C:\Batch\PSEXEC.EXE  -s PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell.exe -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%~dpn0.ps1""' -Verb RunAs}" > E:\Dnload\Sysprep\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt
Pause" I changed the script to this: pastebin.com/cLsjMxxq

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the Start-Transcript command.....

```
Start-Transscript -Path 'C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt'
```

Should read

```
Start-Transcript -Path 'C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt'
```

Comment: Good catch.  Thanks.  I tried writing an empty file to C:\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt from a text editor and I received an error saying "you don't have permission to save in this location", I gave the root permissions.  Then I tried again and I received another error saying "a required privilege is not held by the client" so I Disable The Admin Approval Mode in the group policy.  I can now write to the root of C:\ without running as Admin.  Powershell still won't write the output to the txt file.

Comment: Don't write to root in scripts, it's a needless complication. Use/create a folder for your files.

Comment: I also tried writing to the same folder the script is run from: "E:\Dnload\Sysprep\RemoveAllAppxPackages.txt"  and it won't write to that file.  It doesn't make any difference if the file is not there before the script is run or if there is a blank file.

Comment: There must be a way to see what powershell writes out.  It disappears off the screen in a split second.

Comment: I found a way to run the script in a powershell window.  I fixed a few errors. I can't figure out this error: Get-AppxProvisionedPackage : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At E:\Dnload\Sysprep\RemoveAllAppxPackages3.ps1:28 char:28
+     $ProPackageFullName = (Get-AppxProvisionedPackage | where {$_.Dis ...
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AppxProvisionedPackage], ParameterBindingException

Comment: The error is on this line: $ProPackageFullName = (Get-AppxProvisionedPackage | where {$_.Displayname -like "*$App*"}).PackageName